# Different results for different order of computations with "i"

Tags: complex-numbers

I am really puzzled now:

$\bullet$ First way of thinking: $$(i^{8})^{1/4}=i^{2}=-1$$

$\bullet$ Second way of thinking: $$(i^{8})^{1/4}=(1)^{1/4}=+1$$

I can recall some weird things like these in complex analysis, but which is the correct? Do we pick either of two in a specific context?

Comment: Don't your parenthesis indicate the order of operations?

Comment: The second one is right, isn't it? Contents of parentheses -> Powers from left to right -> Multiplication and division from left to right -> Addition and subtraction from left to right.

Comment: There's also the fact that ${(b^m)}^n$ is not generally equal to $b^{mn}$ for non-positive $b$. This is responsible for many a "proof" that $-1 = 1$.

Comment: I thought so, but Oskar's comment is correct...
pjs Indeed, youre right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth-root is not a single-valued function, it is four-valued (except at $0$).  So $1^{1/4}$ is in fact the set $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$.

Comment: So, I keep the first value of the set in a computation? Does it have to do with complex phases?

Comment: Not necessarily. Think of $w=z^{1/4}$ to be a property of the number $w$ to satisfy $w^4=z$, for a given $z$.  In your example $z=1$ and there are four different $w$'s that satisfy this equation.  It is a standard topic in elementary complex analysis to find the $n$-th roots of the identity by using the polar factorization of complex numbers $z=\rho\exp(i\theta)$ for some real $\rho>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks Oskar, I guess I have to recall these immediately